# Работа с большими объемами данных в React Flux/Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, flux

Существуют ли паттерны работы со store во Flux/Redux, которые бы подразумевали загрузку в них больших объемов данных для последующего их воспроизведениях в других местах приложения.

Например:

Имеется некий список автомобильных брендов с кратким описанием их истории и списком моделей (забираем GET-запросом). Бренды мы можем добавлять/изменять/удалять через конструктор (постим изменения в БД). Этот список используется на странице А, на странице Б, а также в модальном окне.

Так вот, является ли хорошей практикой весь список загружать в store?

Comment: Вообще на самом деле хороший вопрос что делать если эндпоинты по кускам данные не отдают а данных много. Если никто за два дня не ответит, повешу баунти.

Comment: Ну то есть возможно работать с суперпортянкой в стейте и не проблема вовсе, но если это не проблема, то было бы замечательно если бы кто-нибудь объяснил почему это не проблема =)

Comment: Я сначала был уверен, что этого делать нельзя, теперь меня одолевают сомнения) Вопрос действительно интересный.

Comment: Вопрос все еще актуален. Стоит ли store использовать, как кэш?

Comment: @Harvey, стоп, а причем тут кэш? Если вы используете один из способов клиент-серверной _передачи данных_, то там почти наверняка есть кэш из коробки (например HTTP кэш в REST). Стор тут как бы не причем...

Comment: @Harvey, другое дело, если все эти большие объемы данных нужны в приложении

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, описанный в сабже пример является альтернативой кешированию запросов. Делема, как раз в том, насколько правильно переносить логику кэша в стор, параллель тут очевидна: если не использовать store для хранения "больших данных", то мы будем кешировать запросы, если использовать, то мы будем делать один запрос, а дальше хранить и манипулировать ими в store.

Comment: @Harvey, лично я очень сильно сомневаюсь, что использование стора для кэширования - хорошая идея. Проблемы начнутся, когда вы задумаетесь об инвалидации. Очень сомневаюсь, что вам удастся создать хоть что-то более-менее схожее по эффективности с HTTP кэшем. Но давайте подождем, возможно кто-то даст развернутый ответ с кучей аргументов и ссылок на авторитеты =)

Comment: @Dmitry Simushev, нет задачи найти кэшу альтернативу, просто логика его работы пересекается со способом использования store, описанном в сабже

Answer (score 6):

Я использую redux и все сказанное дальше распространяется на него, про flux ничего не скажу, там все мутно раньше было, куча реализаций и тп (сейчас не знаю).

И так в идеале вы сохраняете ВСЕ состояние приложения в store, именно все. Заполнили поле формы - в store, поменяли состояние кнопки в store, загружаете данные - флаг loading должен быть в store, данные загрузились - должны быть в store. Но мир не идеальный и поэтому мелкие вещи, типа "состояние плитки: перевернута" лучше хранить локально в state компонента.

Плюсы:

- отлично работает undo\redo функционал в redux-devtools
- вы можете буквально сохранить store при ошибке и возпроизвести у себя
- минимум теневой логики, искать баги очень просто
- почти все компоненты stateless... просто рендер того самого состояния

У вас выходит огромный объект со всеми данными приложения. Но такой огромный он не нужен для каждого компонента, по этому вы используете `reselect` (ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО ИЛИ ПОДОБНОЕ РЕШЕНИЕ, он вытаскивает маленький объект с данными из общего состояние оптимизациями, работает очень круто, бояться огромного store с ним не нужно).

Кстати для загрузки данных можете использовать `redux-api` (не самое изящное решение, но довольно мощное) и `react-redux-form` (очень изящное).

Посмотрите серию скринкастов от разработчика redux, очень много вопросов отпадает
https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-the-single-immutable-state-tree

Comment: В ClojureScript в основной массе такой подход и используют. Что в Om, что в Re-frame (который даже упомянут в ридми reselect). В JS, возможно, не самый приятный синтаксис для таких вещей, но с этим можно жить.

Comment: @alexes, спасибо за мнение, наконец-то )
Меня в подходе "Все сохраняем в store", смущает то, что комфорт и скорость разработки сильно страдают. Помимо того, что в реакте нельзя даже в state записать данные без гемороя (если есть вложенные объекты), то в случае со store, все еще больше усложняется: на каждую банальную операцию смены модели придется пилить экшны, редюсеры. Разработка самого небольшого компонента выльется в издевательство над разработчиком и большие временные затраты. Я понимаю, если заливать в стор данные, которые используются где-то еще на странице, но все состояния - это ппц

Comment: Почему нельзя хранить в store только общие данные, используещиеся какими то дугими компонентами, а все остальное (промежуточные состояния компонента) лить в state? Чем это не круто?

Comment: @Harvey геморой - это писать какую либо логику в компонентах. Как раз логика в reducers самое крутое, что можно делать. И как раз скорость разработки и комфорт возрастает очень сильно. Страдает производительность, но с reselect, оверхед не такой большой.

Comment: Чаще всего reducers ОЧЕНЬ простые, очень легко тестятся https://gist.github.com/alexesDev/a919a81b6e5c6a060fb6dc17ba817176

Comment: Reducer и экшены (именно так назвать не корректно, потому что в redux action - объект, а функции в actions - это action creator)... так вот, в общем это чистые функции, чем больше таких функций у вас в проекте - тем проще вам. Компоненты со state не являются чистыми.

Comment: Кстати маленькие компоненты у вас должны быть чаще всего stateless. Просто чистая функция. Умные компоненты, которые цепляются к store должны быть только на самом верху. Чистые компоненты в папке components, умные (работающие с redux)  в папке pages.

Comment: Столько нюансов, можно вести блог. Ещё бы научиться связно писать =)

Comment: @alexes, все таки не могу понять, предлагаете все в стор загружать или делить компоненты на чистые и использующие стор? По какому принципу делить? Чем плох компромисный подход?

Comment: Последние пару лет я работал с Ангуляром и после него разработка на Реакт мне кажется мукой. Вместо того, чтобы сосредоточиться на самой сути - программировании логики, приходится писать кучу геттеров сеттеров, мучаться с манипуляцией данных. Каждый день пытаюсь найти причину по которой так много людей любят Реакт и у меня не получается. Вероятно, просто-напросто, кому-то нравится писать все "вручную", работать с более чистым и контролируемым кодом, т.е. с Реактом, а кому то ближе Ангуляр с его подкопотной логикой, но позволяющей тебе сосредоточиться на решении задачи. Сори за офтоп

Comment: Не совсем понял вопросы, мы вроде говорим где хранить данные. Я говорю, что в идеале все данные должны быть в store, а не в state компонента и вообще state используется в исключительных ситуациях, для оптимизации (например состояние кнопки normal или hover можно хранить в store, но это будет ужастно для производительности и нет особо смысла, а вот checked состояние стоит уже хранить в store).

Comment: Смысл всей этой байды - избавиться от событий. Есть только одно событие - обработать action, после чего возникает новый state (у store) и все приложение перерисовывается. Я не писал никогда на angular, но помню со времен backbone, что среднее и большое приложение в какой-то момент привращается в жуткий ад сотни событий... тут одно событие, которое обрабатывается большой функцией и выдает новые данные - все. Ничего не скрыто, все явно. Минус - производительность полной перерисовки, но react и reselect убирают эту проблему.

Comment: @alexes, я никак не могу понять зачем ВСЕ данные лить в store. например у нас есть модуль в приложении, выполняющий одну конкретную задачу? Он получает данные с сервера, изменяет их и отправляет обратно серверу. Так работает большинство модулей приложения. Зачем в этом случае мне использовать store? 
Модули приложения должны быть автономны. Хранение ВСЕХ данных в store эту парадигму разрушает, потому что порождает зависимость модуля от данных в store. В общем считаю, что данные на уровне модуля, которых кстати, как правило, большинство должны храниться в state, а публичные данные в store

Comment: Я написал пару сообщений, но стер. Может я в чем-то не прав. Но есть один железный аргумент. Если хранить все в store, то тестирование - почти рай. Подменить store и reducer - проще простого. Тестировать reducer и action creator - просто как два пальца, это простые функции. А как вы будете тестировать ваш компонент, который делать запросы к серверу? (да, моки, подмена метода и тп, но это жутко неудобно)

Comment: @alexes, понятно. В общем и целом спасибо за ответ и аргументы. Опробуем этот подход